# CodeIgniter mail silently not sending

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I have tried and developed an application with mail sending functionality in CodeIgniter.
Early mail worked, but mail is not sending.
There are no errors reported. It says Mail Sending Successfully, but I haven't received mail.

Controller Code:

```
public function mail() { 
     $from_email = "tamilshanmugamit460@gmail.com";

     //Load email library 
     $this->load->library('email'); 

     $this->email->from($from_email, 'Your Name'); 
     $this->email->to($from_email);
     $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
     $this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 

     //Send mail 
     if($this->email->send()) 
     echo "Email sent successfully."; 
     else 
     echo "Error in sending Email.";
  }
```

Comment: did you happen to check in the spam folder ?

Comment: Yes Checked. Even i have changed the mail id but it is not working bro

Comment: Is it the first time you are using the `email` library? if so, have you configured it by `$this->email->initialize($config)` ?

Comment: I have used and now using $config = array('mailtype'=>'html');
          $this->load->library('email',$config);

Comment: what about other smtp params? `protocol, smtp_host, smtp_user, smtp_pass, smtp_port`

Comment: $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
   $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
   $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
   $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

   $this->email->initialize($config);

Answer (score 0):

Use this method hope it will help you

Email configuration

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['smtp_user'] = "user-email";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
$config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']    = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Email sending code

```
$this->email->from('your-email', 'Name');
$this->email->to($to_email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send()
```

Comment: It Says Call to undefined method Assign::sendemail()

Comment: It is working perfect for me.

Comment: use this for email debug 

show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

Comment: Bro i have initialized email library . is i need load any more library?

Comment: this is for email error handling